# Best way to represent NULL in a column that represents a type

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given a table with a column that represents a type `A` or `B` or `None`, how should the `None` be represented? As a `NULL` or explicitly `None` or something else?

Comment: Please provide your data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would advocate in favor of using `NULL` to represent the absence of data. Rationale:

- `null` will never conflict with other values - so if one you eventually comes up with a *actual* value of `'None'`, this is not a problem
- `null` works across datatypes, so it can be used consistently across different tables or columns to represent "missing" data (which saves you the burden of choosing, then remembering the value you picked for each and every column)

Answer (score 0):

The technical meaning of `NULL` is "unknown", not "missing" or "none".  It is often used for "unknown".

However, if you have three types, "A", "B", and "none", then have three values.

If you have two types, "A" and "B" and some records are neither, then use `NULL`.

Comment: One other call out is a "NULL" value will take up less space in your Database as opposed to other values.